# Natural Domain of Functions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

> Find the natural domain of $f(x,y) = \ln( xy)$

How does this graph look like? Is it the $\frac{1}{x}$ graph with the top part shaded? And did I do this correctly?

$\ln$ function is undefined for values $\leq 0$

Therefore,
$$ xy > 0 \\y > \frac{1}x $$
$$\{x,\ y: y > \frac{1}{x},\  x,y \in \mathbb R\}$$

Comment: How did you get from $xy>0$ to $y > 1/x$ ?

Comment: I divided by x on both sides

Comment: 0 divided by x is what?

Comment: ahhh yikes...that was so stupid of me. it's 0. so domain is {y : y > 0,y element of R}?

Comment: Is the point (-1,-1) in the domain?

Comment: yes. that means my answer is wrong. but how? ok. i've got another idea. use logarithm laws. ln(xy) = ln(x) + ln(y) x > 0 union y > 0.....and this still seems wrong. i'm so lost.

Comment: Review the rules for dividing both sides of an inequality.

Comment: Hi could you please give me the answer or something very close to it. I can't seem to figure it out. I've got my calc II finals in a few hours. My brain is seriously not functioning. Please